# Can't make Windows 10 replace a phrase (NOT MS WORD)

Tags: windows-10, autocorrect

THIS IS NOT FOR MS WORD. I see a similar old question but it doesn't apply to my issue. I can't seem to make autocorrect suggestions (for example misspelled words underlined in red in Firefox) work with pairs of words (Win 10 Pro). Perhaps nothing will work, I have tried a couple methods. My idiot fingers move the space around, the one that annoys me the most is "int he" instead of "in the". I can't figure out for the life of me how to: make it flag "int" (at the very least), make it flag "int he" (halfway acceptable), or autocorrect "int he" to "in the" (obviously preferred). Same goes for other stupid typing errors of this type. If it matter there are no suggestions for "int" which I would think isn't a word that Windows would recognize. I.e. it isn't underlining "int" right now).

Comment: Spelling correction mostly occurs at the application level, not the OS level. Phrase replacement ONLY occurs at the application level. What you are asking for is not currently possible within the limits you have defined.

Comment: Try looking at the Windows 10 Spell Check Auto Correct Dictionary and see if that helps.  https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/edit-autocorrect-dictionary-windows-10

Comment: Firefox: persdict.dat has autocorect data